# Does HttpCookie.HttpOnly property allow connection over https?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

When we set the cookie HttpOnly property to true, does the server restrict the cookie over https, or does it allow connection over both http AND https ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It allows both. `HttpOnly` determines whether or not the cookie can be accessed through a client-side script. This has nothing to do with SSL. From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.httponly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Setting the HttpOnly property to true does not prevent an attacker
>   with access to the network channel from accessing the cookie directly.
>   Consider using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) to help protect against
>   this.

You can use the `requireSSL="true"` entry in your web.config to secure your [authentication cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.requiressl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can also use the [`Secure` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.secure%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  to secure an individual cookie.